# Perl - connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, perl, ubuntu-10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect to SQL Server 2005 from Perl and do a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896985/connect-to-sql-server-2005-from-perl-and-do-a-select)

I want to connect to Microsoft SQL server from Perl and Ubuntu 10.10. How can I achieve? point me any links or solutions.

Many Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896985/connect-to-sql-server-2005-from-perl-and-do-a-select

Answer (score 1):

Lots of threads on perlmonks, some for specigic version of SQL Server:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=392385

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=907081

[Google search for more](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux%20sqlserver%20site%3aperlmonks.org)